# Ajax call to Webmethod, cross domain

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, webmethod

I have two Asp projects. On close of a dialog box in project A I am trying to call a static webmethod in project B using ajax call.
Instead of calling the Webmethod it is calling the PageLoad.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string UpdateSession()
    {
        return "Test";

    }

 $(function () {
$('div#DialogDiv').on('dialogclose', function (event) {
    CloseDialog("http://localhost:1330/Application_Default.aspx/UpdateSession");
    return false;
  });
});
function CloseDialog(URL) {
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: URL,
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (response) {
      alert("success");
       },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("Failed to trying to find the method: " + URL );
    }
});
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this with pure javascript

```
function CloseDialog(URL) {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", URL);
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            alert(request.responseText);
            // to convert to JSON object-> JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      } else {
            alert("Failed to trying to find the method: " + URL );
      }
    };
    request.send();

    return false;
}
```

With jQuery I would just do this, you don't need more. It should work with cross-domain too.

```
function CloseDialog(URL) {

    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        success: function (response) {
            jQuery.each(result.list, function(i, val) {
                // iterate the JSON object
                // val.node;
            });
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("Failed to trying to find the method: " + URL );
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but same result as my version, page load still being called.

Comment: Well then I guess your ajax code is just fine! must be the way you access to the URL. I don't know how to help you in this matter. Sorry!